# Not able to share a service instance in IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

im trying to share a services instance between two spaces but when i run this command :

**cf enable-feature-flag service_instance_sharing**

I get this error msg :

**Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action**

It's weird that i'm not authorized because i'm the admin for this account.
I even tried to give SpaceDeveloper role to some users but still having the same error.

So, how can i fix this because we need to share some service instances between a couple of spaces.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `cf enable-feature-flag` requires you to be an operator and have admin permissions. It's not something that an end user can do. No amount of toggling the org or space roles will resolve this.

In short, you need to ask your operator (IBM) to enable this feature, or change to a different provider that has the feature enabled.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I contacted IBM and they don't have this feature available. In IBM cloud there is a concept called Resource Group, that i can use to share services between regions and spaces.